# How can I proceed if my email is not working, and I am in the middle of creating proofs for my new accepted paper

Tags: publications, email

I received an acceptance letter for my article and the letter said that the manuscript will be transferred to the production department and work will begin on the creation of the proof. They also said that if they need any additional information to create the proof they will let me know.

Now the problem is that my establishment email (the email that I was using to communicate) is not working because of problems with the university's servers, and I don't know how long it will take to solve the problem.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Has the problem been going on for days?

Comment: @Jon Custer, Yes.

Comment: Wow. Normally that might be cause for a celebration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many journals have an online system where you can log in and change the e-mail information. If not, just contact the responsible person (by using another e-mail account).